# Customer Portal custom maintenance page

Tags: customer-portal

We'd like to create our own custom maintenance page and time windows when we do our own updates to customer portal. We'd like once a user logs in to be communicated about the incoming maintenance window and also to kick them out once the window starts with a custom "down for maintenance" page.

Login hours can do the second part, but no custom page. Not sure how to do an incoming maintenance page for logged in users (works for non-authenticated).

Comment: Are you using a traditional portal or Force.com Sites?